# Kernel Error with Jupyter Notebook (Anaconda) Setup, New to computers

Tags: python, terminal, kernel, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am very new to coding and using the terminal and everything of the sorts.

I want to use jupyter notebook but when I run it it gives me this Kernel Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 516, in wrapper
    result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 75, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1063, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 307, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 94, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 257, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 203, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\saiya\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I recently got a new computer, downloaded Python 3, Anaconda with Python 3, Git Bash, and Atom. I uninstalled everything but Atom, and reinstalled Anaconda just to get that error whenever I try to use Jupyter Notebook.

I've tried running `python -m ipykernel install --user` in the terminal.

When I run "jupyter kernelspec list" this is what I see:
Available kernels:

```
python3    C:\Users\saiya\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

[image]

Please help me I'm so lost and new to using computers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution below worked for me.
You can either run this code in command prompt in your virtual environment OR in the Anaconda prompt.

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

For detailed explanation and instructions have a look [here.](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3)